# Error "Failed connect to github.com"

Tags: linux, git, github

I am a beginner to start with git. I have created my account on github. I created a new repository. But I am not able to push or update changes in github using the terminal. I am running the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/TestApplication
cd ~/TestApplication
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/vinayptl/TestApplication.git
git push origin master
```

When I execute last command `git push origin master`, it freezes for some time and give following error:

```
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing 
https://github.com/vinayptl/TestingApplication.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I am working on Linux Platform. What could be the problem? I have seen some of the answers from SO but not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this [repository exist on github yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658606/import-existing-source-code-to-github)? Have you successfully checked out a repo from github on this machine (i.e. are your ssh keys setup correctly)?

Comment: i just have started using github and yes this repository exist on github. i am just following the steps given in https://help.github.com. so i have not setup ssh connection but here i am using HTTP for connection

Comment: You could try the SSH URL to see if that works: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/TestApplication.git`.

Comment: no its not working. is it some firewall issue

Comment: `curl -v https://github.com/vinayptl/TestingApplication.git/info/refs` might shed some light on that. Also `ping -c1 github.com` to just double-check that it actually is going to github (I get `207.97.227.239`).

Comment: When I tried to clone that repo, it asked for username and password, which I can only assume means that "it works" - since I don't know those details, I couldn't go fruther...

Comment: ping -c1 github.com is failing.I am not able to connect to github server(207.97.227.239).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a proxy in place, ping won't help you much ([it cannot ping through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147558/proxy-for-command-line-utilities-in-win-xp)).

You need to set `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variable.
See:

- "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)".
- "[`git push -u origin master` error: Received HTTP code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875550/git-push-u-origin-master-error-received-http-code-0/10876451#10876451)"
- "[Cannot get Http on git to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073504/cannot-get-http-on-git-to-work/7073618#7073618)"